# How to obtain qubit's amplitude in qiskit

Tags: qiskit

For example, I have some circuit

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
```

After operations:

```
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
```

probability amplitudes of the qubits will change.

I know that I can estimate them by measuring qubits a bunch of times and normalizing the `counts`:

```
result = execute(circuit, backend, shots=1000).result()
counts  = result.get_counts(circuit)
```

But is there a way to directly obtain true amplitudes? Yeah, it's impossible in real life, but I hope the information is contained under the hood of `qiskit` for education purposes.

Comment: By "true amplitudes", do you mean the theoretical probabilities of each state? For example: a qubit with a single H-gate would have two possible states, either 0 or 1, both with probability 1/sqrt(2) (normalized to 1/2). So would the 1/2 be the "true amplitude"? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @MatthewStypulkoski, yes I mean them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get these "true amplitudes" through the use of the `statevector_simulator` within Aer. If you execute the circuit on the `statevector_simulator` backend, it will return a statevector for the circuit. This statevector, when normalized, will return the theoretical probabilities of each state.

Let's take the circuit you posted as an example:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.cx(0, 1)

# Retrieve the statevector_simulator backend
backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')

result = execute(circuit, backend, shots=1000).result()

# Get the statevector from result().
statevector = result.get_statevector(circuit)

# Normalize statevector to receive the true probabilities.
```

The statevector will be in the form of a list, with each entry representing a possible state. In this example, the statevector would be returned as `[0.70710678+0.j 0.        +0.j 0.        +0.j 0.70710678+0.j]`. This can be read as:

- State `00` probability = 0.70710678+0.j (which is $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$)
- State `01` probability = 0
- State `10` probability = 0
- State `11` probability = 0.70710678+0.j (which is $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$)

Which, when normalized would give you a 50% probability of the state `00` and a 50% probability of the state `11`.